# Can I use L6 Auth scaffolding as purely an API alongside tymon/jwt-auth?

Tags: laravel

My intention is to build a decoupled frontend separately. But since the auth scaffolding provides a lot of stuff like login, verify, email, reset, signup, I still want to avoid rewriting the logic myself. I might have a few unique signup fields but other than that simple.

Comment: I suppose you can, if you are going to be using API auth it should work because i am certain its the same logic used by Passport for auth

Comment: I am not planning on using Passport, but I was imaging how using the scaffolding would work as an API as its very hard wired to the blade stuff.

Comment: You are onto rocket science buddy :) I was thinking your question was a ```yes``` or ```no``` so i had said yes. Passport was just an illustration on why i had said yes

Comment: "very hard wired to the blade stuff"? how so?

Comment: btw if you don't need blade I hacked Laravel to be pure stateless API [here](https://github.com/CaddyDz/laravel-api)

Comment: Basically I intend to confirm, if using the Auth scaffolding with a stateless approach whilst using tymon/jwt-auth is possible while retaining all those forgot/verify emails and the controller logic for authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no. You'll need to create API endpoints for everything your decoupled app needs to access, including login, registration, password-reset, etc.

However, there are quite a few boilerplates you can use as a starting point. This repo has all the auth controllers and routes to get you started https://github.com/devinsays/laravel-react-bootstrap (uses tymon/jwt-auth). It also has tests for the auth endpoints you can copy over.